# Infinitely assigning a SharedPreference , but how?

Tags: java, android, android-preferences

I'm making a app and I have this function which is infinitely assigning a UserPreference to a string and I do not understand why.

The java file:

```
public class generalSettings extends PreferenceActivity {
           @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.general_settings);

        List<Schedule> schedules = getSchedule();  

        if (schedules.isEmpty()) {
            from.setSummary("--:--");
            to.setSummary("--:--");
        } else {

            from.setSummary(schedules.get(0).getStartTime());
            to.setSummary(schedules.get(0).getEndTime());

        }


    private List<Schedule> getSchedule() {
        String cameraServiceSchedule = UserSharedPref.initializeSharedPreferencesForcameraServiceSchedule(getApplicationContext()).getString(UserSharedPref.cameraServiceSchedule, "");
        String[] scheduleStrings = cameraServiceSchedule.split(";");
        List<Schedule> schedules = new ArrayList<>();

        Log.d("TESTa:",cameraServiceSchedule);

        for (String scheduleString : scheduleStrings) {
            String[] times = scheduleString.split(",");
            if (times.length == 2) {
                try {

                    Log.d("TEST:","adding only 1");
                    schedules.add(new Schedule(Integer.parseInt(times[0]), Integer.parseInt(times[1])));
                    break;

                } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {

                    Log.d("TEST:","getting a NumberFormatException");
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return schedules;
        }
    }
   }
```

Schedule.java:

```
public class Schedule {

    private  Integer startTime;
    private  Integer endTime;

    public Schedule() {

    }
    public Schedule(Integer startTime, Integer endTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }

    public  Integer getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    public  void setStartTime(Integer startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }

    public  Integer getEndTime() {
        return endTime;
    }

    public void setEndTime(Integer endTime) {
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }
}
```

When I'm logging this `2018-11-01 17:19:27.445 4346-4346/? D/TESTa:: 891,1131;` at different times is being printed continuously till the application runs.

So, Testa is printing indefinitely which is the logging output of `cameraServiceSchedule` which is just initialised from User Preference file, but why, it's not even in a loop to be initialised again and again.
 and the same object `schedules.get(0)` is being overwritten again and again when I do this `List<Schedule> schedules = getSchedule();` I logged this as well. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Any particular reason why this is a `PreferenceActivity`?

Comment: why using a list ? to store prefs when you only have two values

Comment: Well, I'm working on settings page using PreferenceScreen. You can also see am addPreferencesFromResource(), am adding from a "xml" directory rather than a "layout".

Comment: and wont it be better if you extend activity to a simple activity and store prefs using the claiical method

Comment: Well, I'am just an intern those functions were not made by me, and the less I change code made by the employee the better. @Har Kal

Comment: Am a beginner no idea "activity to a simple activity" @Har Kal

Comment: Apart from a pretty bad name, what is `UserSharedPref.initializeSharedPreferencesForcameraServiceSchedule`?

Answer (score 0):

use this approach 
this will work for sure

this is your main activity

```
/**
 * Created by harkal on 01-11-2018.
 */

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ScheduleData scheduleData = new ScheduleData(this);
        if(scheduleData.getSchedule() == null){
            //set schedule here
            scheduleData.setSchedule(new Schedule(0, 0)); //set the schedule here i have put 0 just like that
        }else{
            //get the data and use it
            int startTime = scheduleData.getSchedule().getStartTime(); //this is the starting time use it how ever you want
            int endTime = scheduleData.getSchedule().getEndTime(); //similarly this is the ending time use it how ever you want
        }

    }
}
```

this is your shared prefs class

```
/**
 * Created by harkal on 01-11-2018.
 */


public class ScheduleData {

    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    private static final String SCHEDULE_DATA = "SCHEDULE_DATA";
    private static final String SCHEDULE = "SCHEDULE";

    public ScheduleData(Context context) {
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(SCHEDULE_DATA , 0);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    }

    public void setSchedule(Schedule schedule) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(schedule);
        editor.putString(SCHEDULE, json);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public Schedule getSchedule() {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = sharedPreferences.getString(SCHEDULE, null);
        return gson.fromJson(json, Schedule.class);
    }

}
```

this is the schedule object file

```
/**
 * Created by harkal on 01-11-2018.
 */

public class Schedule {

    private int startTime;
    private int endTime;

    public Schedule() {

    }

    public Schedule(int startTime, int endTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }

    public int getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    public void setStartTime(int startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }

    public int getEndTime() {
        return endTime;
    }

    public void setEndTime(int endTime) {
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }
}
```

i have used google's gson library 
just paste this line in your app gradle file

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
```

hope it helps you
happy coding :)

if any problem 
leme know it

Comment: Hey, appreciate the answer but, why do you think I'am getting that error, I should not be getting an infinity assign error it's not even in a loop. But, it is getting assigned infinitely many times...why??......have any ideas...?

Comment: the error is occurring because you are using list to store data i think so